# Adding attenuations in dB

Tags: math, attenuation

I am writing a synthesizer. One part of the synthesizer specification says that different sources can specify an attenuation to be applied to a signal, and that these attenuations *should be summed*.

The attenuations are specified in cB **and are given as positive values**. An attenuation of 0cB means no attenuation.

The naive approach, which I've tried, would be:

$$
x_{total} = 20 \log_{10}\left( \sum 10^{\frac{x}{20}}\right)
$$

for each $x$ as the attenuation (converted to dB) being summed.

This has problems, since if I add two 0cB attenuations (i.e. no attenuation, twice), I get a total attenuation of 60.2cB. This is obviously not what I want.

How can I add my attenuations to get a sensible result out the other side? Thank you.

Comment: I assume that a 'cB' is a centi-bel, i.e., 1/10th of a decibel?

Comment: @TimWescott Correct

Comment: If so then your factors of 20 above should be factors of 200.  I'm answering your question assuming dB.

Comment: sorry, I mentioned in the question that I am converting my centibels to decibels before I use them in that formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the advantages of using dB to express gain or attenuation is that they're inherently logarithmic.

So if you're speaking in dB, when you *add* a 10dB attenuation to another 10dB of attenuation, what you're saying is that you're *multiplying* the signal by $\sqrt{0.1}$, and then by $\sqrt{0.1}$ again.  The result is 20dB of attenuation -- or multiplying the signal by $\sqrt{0.01} = 0.1$.

So if your ultimate gain is $A$, as a normal number, and you have attenuations $a_1, a_2, \cdots$ in dB, then the actual $A$ by which you multiply your signal is $$A = 10^{-\frac{1}{20}\sum a_n}$$